# Change NGINX Binary in Heroku PHP Buildpack

Tags: heroku, nginx, dokku

I'd like to use nginx within a dokku/heroku setting with the ssl module enabled:

```
+    --with-http_ssl_module
```

What is the easiest way to achieve that? Cloning the php buildpack alone does not do the trick. How can I recompile the nginx binary? How can I rebuild a buildpack?

Answer (score 0):

ok - i did it like this:

- forked the buildpack
- changed the nginx dependency to 1.10:

  `$require["heroku-sys/nginx"] = "~1.10.0";`

  in platform.php
- then compiled and stored a new nginx package (based on the official heroku one)
- stored the package somwhere public on amazon s3
- added to the app environment the line `export HEROKU_PHP_PLATFORM_REPOSITORIES='https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/packages.json'`

If deploying an app, nginx will be loaded from your custom repository and installed within the docker image.